# Please help :( SQL question! Select distinct statement within case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one column that is all animals (cats, dogs, snakes, toads, etc.) and a column that is ismammal (TRUE, FALSE). I would like to get the unique mammal values from the animals column. I was thinking it would be a case statement to weed out the nonmammals and then select from only mammals using Select Distinct

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your title to a non-emotional short summary of your question: you'll get more responses that way. Second, please add some SQL to your question, including the table definition and your select statement even if its not currently working.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a case here, it's just this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT animal
FROM yourTable
WHERE IsMammal = 'TRUE'
```

Comment: Thank you! if the TRUE, FALSE values in IsMammal are stored as text should it be Where IsMammal = "TRUE"

Comment: @Christina Yep, I'll edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT DISTINCT animals
FROM your_table
WHERE ismammal = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(animals) FROM [TableName] WHERE ismammal = 'TRUE'
```